# How to use the react-native version 0.64.2 to upload image using the image picker to AWS S3 bucket (android app project)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3

I am try to upload picture to AWS S3 bucket by using react native version 0.64.2 but it keep give the error below

"headers": Object {},
"status": 0,
"text": "Stream Closed",

the function code I type so far:

```
function handleChoosePhoto() {
    const options = {}
    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, response => {
        if (response.didCancel) {
            console.log('User cancelled image picker')
        }
        else if (response.error) {
            console.log('Imagepicker Error: ', response.error)
        }
        else {
            console.log(response)
            const imgContent = {
                uri: response.assets[0].uri,
                name: response.assets[0].fileName,
                type: 'image/type'
            }
            const testdefg = {
                keyPrefix: 'uploads/',
                bucket: 'testwetmart-bucket',
                region: 'use-east-2',
                accessKey: 'AKIASX2RQ4PYBNZHVXKY',
                secretKey: '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',
                successActionStatus: 201
            }
            return RNS3.put(imgContent, testdefg)
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.status !== 201) {
                        console.log("Error")
                    }
                    console.log(response.status)
                    console.log(response.body)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('fail')
                    console.log(error)
                })
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: What did you tried so far? Do you have some code to share?

Comment: I plan to use a button to fire this function to pick image and upload image to AWS S3 (android app project)